# Java - synchronizing multiple threads on time-step basis

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have a Master that keeps a list of SlaveThread objects. On each time step, I want the Master to run the SlaveThreads in parallel, however, at the end of the time step, I want the SlaveThreads to to wait for each other to complete the current time step before advancing forward. Also, I don't want to reinstantiate the SlaveThreads on each time step. I have 2 possible solutions, and I don't know how to make either of them work:

1) The run() method in SlaveThread is in a while(true) loop. After the execution of a single loop in the SlaveThread, I'll have SlaveThread notify the Master(which I don't know how to do), and the Master does something like

```
try{
    for (int i = 0; i < numSlaveThreads; i++) {
        while (!slaveThreads[i].getCompletedThisIter()) {
        wait()
        }
      }
  System.out.println("Joined");
```

}

before advancing to the next time step. How would I do this? How can I have a single SlaveThread notify just the master?

2) The run() in Slave is not in while(true) loop, then I have to call start() on it on every iteration. But the thread state of the Slave at this point will be terminated. How can I call start() on it again without reinstantiating it?

Comment: Sounds like you want a cyclic barrier: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html (Using variant 1.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is exactly what barriers are for, you can realize this with a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) or a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). These are synchronizers used to **delay the progress** of threads until the desired state is reached, in your case the threads have completed their computation.

Here it depends on the details how you want to realize:

> Latches are for waiting for events; barriers are for waiting for other
>   threads.

For the `CyclicBarrier` that would done in the following fashion:

```
// whereby count is the number of your slave threads
this.barrier = new CyclicBarrier(count);
```

Then in the `Runnable` definition of your slaves you will insert at the end of the computation: `barrier.await()`

```
public class Slaves implements Runnable {

   // ...

   @Override
   public void run() {

      while(condition) {

         // computation
         // ...

         try {
            // do not proceed, until all [count] threads
            // have reached this position
            barrier.await();
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            return;
         } catch (BrokenBarrierException ex) {
            return;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Your slave threads will not proceed, until all your threads have finished the computation. This way you do not need to realize signaling between another master thread.

If, however, you have some code you want to execute after all threads have reached that position (master signaling) you can pass an additional `Runnable` to the `CyclicBarrier` constructor, which will be executed after all threads have arrived at the barrier.

```
this.barrier = new CyclicBarrier(count,
   new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         // signal your master thread, update values, etc.
      }
    }
 );
```

Comment: I want to wait for other threads to tell the master that they are done with their current iteration (so that they can all at the same time proceed to the next one)

Comment: How do I make the cyclic barrier restart the count at the end of 1 iteration? You said that each thread by calling await() decreases the counter by 1 until it gets to 0, but at that point, I want to restart the counter back to numThreads, so that the next cycle gets executed.

Comment: @Trup You don't have to worry about that, this happens automatically, that's why it is called *cyclic* barrier, it can be reused as often as you want.

Comment: And how would I count the total number of iterations executed? (the total number of time steps)

Comment: @Trup You could for instance increment an integer value in the optional `Runnable` you can pass to the constructor as I have explained at the end of my answer.

Comment: Would this integer be a field of the master class? Can you please show me how that would look? And how would I kill the Slaves once this number is reached? It is not clear to me what to do at the Master, can you please help me with this?

Comment: @Trup Whether the integer will be a field of your master class is up to you, that is program design and cannot be answered generically. Maybe you should stop thinking about a master thread, you just have some worker threads that do the work. You can terminate the worker threads by setting the while condition to false or interrupt the threads with `Thread.interrupt()` there is even an `InterruptedException` case for that in the code sample I gave.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a combination of an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to manage your threads (i.e. you recycle your threads without having to create new ones at each cycle) and a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) which will synchronize all the slaves.

See below a simple example where the master launches the slaves in a loop, making sure they are all done before starting again. The slaves, being a bit lazy, just sleep for some (not really random) time:

```
public class Test {

    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    private static final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(5); //4 slaves + 1 master

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable master = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println("Starting slaves");
                        for (int i = 100; i < 500; i += 100) {
                            executor.submit(getRunnable(i));
                        }
                        barrier.await();
                        System.out.println("All slaves done");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Bye Bye");
                }
            }
        };

        executor.submit(master);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        executor.shutdownNow();

    }

    public static Runnable getRunnable(final int sleepTime) {
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Entering thread " + Thread.currentThread() + " for " + sleepTime + " ms.");
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    System.out.println("Exiting thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                    barrier.await();
                } catch (BrokenBarrierException | InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: Which is the code for the slaves? Also, can I just do it with a cyclic barrier and no execution service? Can you show me how this would look? Basically, I want to see explicitly how the  slave tells the cyclic barrier it is done, and how the master uses the cyclic barrier to wait for all slaves to finish. Thanks!

Comment: The slaves' runnables are generated by `getRunnable(i)`. You can use a cyclicbarrier without the executorservice. You only need to setup the barrier with the right number. Everytime `barrier.await()` is called, the calling thread waits and that number is decremented. When the number reaches 0 all the waiting threads start working again.

Comment: I suggest you run the program I posted to see how it works and adapt it for your needs.